# How to modify CSS / HTML of Jekyll themes on Github Pages?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I set up a GitHub pages website and so far I've just been modifying the site content by playing around with the ReadMe file in my repo. I wanted to change the site title so I looked up how to do this, people online mentioned changing the title tag in my _config.yml file (which worked).

My question is what if I want to go beyond just modifying and adding tags? Like what if I want to change the css / html of the file? There's this button on my page that I don't even know how to remove because I don't have access to like an index.html or anything like that.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Gitbash, From Gitbash You Can Should Config With Github And Upload Local File To Github. For Example Git Add *, git commit -m "added", git push -u origin master. If You Want To Change Anything Just Change The Local File And Update It By Command. Git Add *, git push -u origin master.